# Colorbox popup on specific table column instead of row

Tags: jquery, html-table, colorbox

I created Colorbox popup when a user click on anywhere in the table row by using below code. Now I want to open the popup only if someone click the 2nd column.

```
$(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});

<tr class="inline" href="#123">
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
</tr>

<div style='display:none'>
     <div id='123' class="colorbox_content">
          <p><strong>Title Here</strong></p>
          <p>Description</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

I try to apply class on `td` and also tried to change jQuery from `$(".inline")` to `$("table td #2")` but nothing worked.

Comment: `$('table > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(2)') `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

> ```
> $('table > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(2)').colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
> ```

You can get away with a shorter selector, you'd have to experiment. There is a `> tbody` in there whether you put one there or not, because the browser will place it there by default. When traversing the DOM, that's an important thing to remember about tables.

**SNIPPET**

```js
$('table > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(2)').css('background', 'red');
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks man, working perfect. I tried the same before but forgot to put `table > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(2)` in another jQuery script which let the popup open in DataTables.

Comment: one related question if I want to apply on 5 columns except the 1st, is there any shortcut way like `td:nth-of-type(!1)`

Comment: You can try `:not('td:nth-of-type')`, but that might be too complex for [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) Let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on a table cell the event is propagated to the table row.

It's enough to stop the propagation of the click event.

If you are using [https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox](https://rawgit.com/jackmoore/colorbox/master/jquery.colorbox-min.js) you cannot attach the colorbox to the second cell because you have attached the colorbox to the table row using the href attribute.

So, my proposal is:

```js
$(".inline").colorbox({
  inline: true, width: "50%",
  open: false
});
$(".inline td").on('click', function (e) {
  if ($(this).index() != 1) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jackmoore/colorbox/master/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="inline" href="#123">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Address</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='123' class="colorbox_content">
        <p><strong>Title Here</strong></p>

        <p>Description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```